# Click and selector :not - not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Why selector :not - not working? After click on red area, opened alert. Why?

```
<div class='content'>

    <div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#EEE;">

        <div id="click" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:red"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
$("body:not(#click)").on("click",  function(event) {

alert(event.target.id);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either stop propagation or check the condition in the click handler.

Your selector `body:not(#click)` will look for the body element whose id is not `click`, in your case body don't have an id so it will add the handler to body element

```
$("body").on("click", function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#click').length) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/py3z5kba/2/)

---

Using stop propagation

```
$("body").on("click", function (event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});

$("#click").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/py3z5kba/1/)

- [The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)